# Reflection emit to generate simple inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to generate following hierarchy of classes dynamically via `reflection.emit`:

```
public class Main
{
    public class A { A(){} }
    public class B : A { B() : base() {} }
}
```

Here is program which I am tried to run on `.net core` framework (similar program is used on `.net` but exception is the same):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AssemblyBuilder assemBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName() { Name = "DynamicAssembly" }, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        TypeBuilder main_builder = assemBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule").DefineType("Main", TypeAttributes.Public);

        TypeBuilder a_builder = main_builder.DefineNestedType("A", TypeAttributes.NestedPublic);
        TypeBuilder b_builder = main_builder.DefineNestedType("B", TypeAttributes.NestedPublic, a_builder);

        var a_constr = a_builder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
        var b_cnstr = b_builder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes);

        {
            //  Creation b constructor    
            var il_gen = b_cnstr.GetILGenerator();
            il_gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il_gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, a_constr);
            il_gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
        a_builder.CreateType();
        b_builder.CreateType();
        main_builder.CreateType();
    }
}
```

But during execution program fails at `b_builder.CreateType()` with exception message (Here is `.net core` function which I cannot debug):
[image]

Is it `reflection.emit` bug? I have no idea what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line of the `TypeBuilder.CreateType` remark section in the documentation tells us:

> If this type is a nested type, the CreateType method must be called on the enclosing type before it is called on the nested type

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

So change the call order and it should work:

```
main_builder.CreateType();
a_builder.CreateType();
b_builder.CreateType();
```

see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bxYCQb

Comment: Oh, thanks)) it is so my stupid mistake. I definitely should reread documentation

Comment: The msdn documentation is actually quite good for reflection.